# Django annotate a field based on info from another database without ORM

Tags: django, django-queryset

I would like to annotate a QuerySet with the info from another database table

- User model has fields 'user_id' in Database A with ORM
- Address table has fields 'user_id' and 'address' in Database B without ORM, i.e. only raw sql is available.

So I would like to do somthing like this:

`Users.objects.annotate(addr="B__address if A_user_id == B__user_id")`
is this even possible?

---

I am thinking
`Users.objects.annotate(addr=RawSQL('select user_id, address from B where B.user_id=A.user_id'))`

I don't think this will work though....Can RawSQL run from another DB?

Or,

```
addr_dict = {'user_id1':'addr1', 'user_id2':'addr2', ...}  # from raw sql of B

Users.objects.annotate(addr=addr_dict[usr_id])     # how can I do this?
```

thank!